# Async line read python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

```
async def parsing_bsc_1inch():
    async with aiofiles.open('test.txt', mode='r') as f:
        async for line in f:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
                response = await client.get(line.rstrip())
            print(f'{response} for {line.rstrip()}')


asyncio.run(parsing_bsc_1inch())
```

I want to do async reading of lines in the file (test.txt). Here is the file itself

```
https://www.example.com/
https://www.twitch.tv/
https://www.python-httpx.org/async/
https://habr.com/
https://www.twitch.tv/
https://www.python-httpx.org/async/
```

The fourth site specifically doesn't work (blocked by my ISP). As I see it, I should get the output of line number 5 immediately after the third request, then line number 6 and after that an error about the request for line 4, but I wait 10 seconds and get the error "Traceback (most recent call last):".
Am I doing something wrong or can't the async work the way I think it should?

Comment: you might try wrapping your ```get()``` in a ```try``` block

Comment: ok, thanks, that fixes the error. But I still have to wait about 5-10 seconds for this error to be displayed and only then do the following requests continue

Comment: I think the problem is that the requests have all been fulfilled. BUT the output is only printed when an error occurs and continues from there. Is there any way to fix this?